# Change jquery ui datepicker programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've got a jquery ui datepicker on my page. It's linked to a span not an input. It's currently tweeked to select a week at a time. I've also got two buttons on my page 'Previous Week' and 'Next Week'. I want the buttons to control what's selected by the datepicker. (ie jump forward / backward by one week when pressed).

I'm not sure how to grab the datepicker so I can mess with it (or what I actually mess with - is there a real 'object' there, or is it a just a load of css / html component like 'ui-datepicker-current-day' etc).

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI datepicker?

Comment: yes I'm usring JQuery UI datepicker (I'll ammend my question).

Comment: Ok, Have you read the `setDate` method? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate

Comment: setDate - that's the one I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a real object you can hold a reference to.

example:

```
var datePicker = $("#id").datepicker({firstDay: 1});
```

to know what you can do with it, check:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: `datePicker.datepicker("setDate,date)` the **D** in date needs to be capitalized for the first comment to work.